# my plot y-axis is not ordered when I split the text

Tags: r, string, ggplot2

I am creating this plot and when I try to string wrap the text on the y axis the ordered of the questions gets messy. If I do not wrap the text it remains intact. Where am I mistaking?

So, if I use qtxt4.1 in my code the questions are ordered (1-> 17), if I use qtxt4.2 (string wrapped text) the questions are no longer ordered. Why??

```
      qtxt4 <- c("I am fully satisfied with the safety and hygiene measures implemented by the hotel / restaurant(Q1)",
       "I fully understand why safety and protection measures must be taken against the Sars-cov-2 virus(Q2)",
       "I felt absolutely no threat that I might be infected during my stay at the hotel / restaurant(Q3)",
       "I'm not afraid of being infected with the Sars-Cov-2 virus by other hotel / restaurant customers(Q4)",
       "I consider that the services offered by the hotel are in full compliance with my expectations(Q5)",
       "I am fully satisfied with the safety and hygiene measures in my hotel room(Q6)",
       "I am not afraid of being infected with the Sars-cov-2 virus by restaurant / hotel employees(Q7)",
       "I certainly would not have chosen this restaurant / hotel if I had another option(Q8)",
       "I am convinced that the most effective methods of maintaining safety have been used(Q9)",
       "I'm concerned about public health issues(Q15)",
       "I am particularly concerned about my health and the health of my family(Q16)",
       "I have taken extreme measures for my health and that of my family(Q17)")
       qtxt4.1 <- factor(qtxt4, ordered = TRUE, levels = c("I am fully satisfied with the safety and hygiene measures implemented by the hotel / restaurant(Q1)",
                                                "I fully understand why safety and protection measures must be taken against the Sars-cov-2 virus(Q2)",
                                                "I felt absolutely no threat that I might be infected during my stay at the hotel / restaurant(Q3)",
                                                "I'm not afraid of being infected with the Sars-Cov-2 virus by other hotel / restaurant customers(Q4)",
                                                "I consider that the services offered by the hotel are in full compliance with my expectations(Q5)",
                                                "I am fully satisfied with the safety and hygiene measures in my hotel room(Q6)",
                                                "I am not afraid of being infected with the Sars-cov-2 virus by restaurant / hotel employees(Q7)",
                                                "I certainly would not have chosen this restaurant / hotel if I had another option(Q8)",
                                                "I am convinced that the most effective methods of maintaining safety have been used(Q9)",
                                                "I'm concerned about public health issues(Q15)",
                                                "I am particularly concerned about my health and the health of my family(Q16)",
                                                "I have taken extreme measures for my health and that of my family(Q17)"))

   qnum4 <- c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q5","Q6","Q7","Q8","Q9","Q15","Q16","Q17")

   questions4 <- data.frame(qnum4, qtxt4.1)
   qtxt4.2 <- stringr::str_wrap(qtxt4.1, width = 35)
   questions4 <- data.frame(qnum4, qtxt4.2)


   df_c2%>%
    pivot_longer(-Studies, names_to = "qnum4") %>%
    left_join(questions4, by = "qnum4") %>%
    ggplot(aes(value, qtxt4.2)) +
    geom_point(aes(color = Studies)) +
    labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1, 5)) +
    theme(text = element_text(size = 12)) +
    theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 10))
```

Comment: The issue is that qtxt4 is a factor with the levels set in your desired order. Applying str_wrap converts your factor to a character vector. And hence it gets ordered alphabetically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second example you need to set `qtxt4.2` as an ordered factor.  One way, using `forcats::fct_reorder` would be...

```
questions4 <- data.frame(qnum4, qtxt4.2) %>% 
        mutate(qtxt4.2 = fct_reorder(qtxt4.2, parse_number(qnum4)))
```

This uses `readr::parse_number` to order `qnum4` numerically rather than alphabetically, and uses this to reorder `qtxt4.2`.  Both of these packages are in the `tidyverse`.

Comment: `qtxt4.2 = fct_reorder(qtxt4.2, parse_number(qnum4))
questions4 <- data.frame(qnum4, qtxt4.2)`